# How to get the address of a contract deployed by another contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, addresses

```
// deploy a new purchase contract
function newPurchase()
    public
    payable
    returns(address newContract)
{
    Purchase c = (new Purchase).value(msg.value)(address(msg.sender));
    contracts.push(c);
    lastContractAddress = address(c);
    return c;
}
```

I was going through this code: https://github.com/jacksonng77/StartEscrow/blob/master/StartEscrow.sol

and I got to this part of the code (see code above) where I am having difficulty trying to understand it. (The full code is on the link above) The difficulty is particularlly on this line

```
Purchase c = (new Purchase).value(msg.value)(address(msg.sender));
```

How does this return the address of the contract? Why are we doing a

```
.value(msg.value)
```

and what is the work of

```
(address(msg.sender));
```

Also this line...

```
lastContractAddress = address(c)
```

why can I just say

```
lastContractAddress = c;
```

what is the purpose of address()?

Comment: To answer your last question - the code you've posted doesn't include the declaration of `lastContractAddress`, but its type is most likely `address`, so `address(c)` is required in order to cast `c` to the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not a view function because it modifies and thus will be a transaction so it will not return a value , simply the tx receipt.

The value can be returned to another function however, just not to the user. You'll have to use log for that.

- `(new Purchase)`  - creates new contract , returns an instance so we need to typecast to address (this is since 0.4.15 ish)
- `.value(msg.value)` - send some ether to the new contract we're creating
- `address(msg.sender)` - should be just `msg.sender` and is a parameter for the constructor of the new contract

When not sending value upon creation to the new contract we could just say

```
new Purchase(msg.sender)
```